# Points de suspension pour des dates et noms incomplets dans un roman

Tags: littérature, ponctuation

Une recherche sur un moteur de recherche se révèle infructueuse car me redirige systématiquement sur les règles de ponctuation des points de suspension, ce qui ne concerne pas ma question.

En effet, depuis des années il m'est arrivé de lire des romans qui utilisaient des dates incomplètes terminées par des points de suspension ou des noms entiers remplacés par des points de suspension.
J'ai toujours trouvé ça très étrange.

Par exemple je viens de commencer *Les travailleurs de la mer* de Victor Hugo.
Dans les premières pages "La Christmas de **182...** fut remarquable à Guernesey.".

Je ne me souviens plus de tous livres où j'ai rencontré ceci mais il m'est arrivé de nombreuses fois de lire de telles dates incomplètes ainsi que des noms de personnages incomplets. Par exemple "Mr ..." ou "Mme ...".

A chaque fois, la date précise et le nom précis n'avaient aucune importance pour l'intrigue et cela ne gêne pas la compréhension.
Je suis juste curieux et je voudrais savoir pourquoi ne pas simplement renseigner une date complète ? Inventer un nom ?

Note : je lis quasimment tous mes livres en version dématérialisée, je ne me souviens pas avoir vu ces points de suspension dans un livre papier.

Note 2 : je ne me souviens pas non plus avoir lu ces points de suspension dans autre chose qu'un roman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ces points de suspension se substituent à des portions de texte que l'auteur ne souhaite pas ou ne peut pas écrire. Il s'agit donc d'une absence d'information intentionnelle. Compléter la date tronquée ou attribuer des noms à des personnages qui n'en ont pas irait à l'encontre des intentions de l'auteur.

Ce type de points de suspension n'est pas limité aux romans ou aux œuvres dématérialisées. Ils peuvent remplacer une portion de texte illisible, une information confidentielle ou une portion de texte inutile à la compréhension, bien que dans ce dernier cas, ils soient souvent entourés de crochets: `[...]`.

Je ne sais pas pourquoi l'année 182... est imprécise mais le début d'une piste se trouve peut-être dans *Les Misérables (Cosette)*, écrit quelques années plus tôt, qui contient la phrase suivante :

> La Noël de l'année 1823 fut particulièrement brillante à Montfermeil.

Une autre date qui peut avoir un lien est la mort de Napoléon I<sup>er</sup> en 1821.

Answer (score 1):

Quand je lis un roman avec ce genre d'ellipse, j'ai tendance à imaginer que l'histoire est vraie mais que l'auteur veut en masquer certains repères pour protéger les protagonistes ou les témoins.