# Lecture de date incomplète

Tags: dates

Dans un roman de Courteline, *Messieurs les ronds-de-cuir*, on trouve une date incomplète, le chiffre des unités manque dans le numéro de l'année.

> En janvier 189…, un sieur Quibolle (Grégoire-Victor) décédait à Vanne-en-Bresse (Ain), léguant au musée de cette ville une paire de jumelles marines et deux chandeliers Louis
> XIII.

La question « [Points de suspension pour des dates](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/31654/17649) » fournit une réponse à la question plus ou moins évidente du pourquoi des points de suspension, mais rien sur la façon, ou les façons—pourquoi préjuger qu'il n'y en a qu'une—de lire à haute voix ou dans sa tête une telle date.

Comment lire ces dates ?

Comment: C'est bête mais la question me rappelle les dessins animés ["20X6"](http://www.hrwiki.org/wiki/20X6) de Homestar Runner, où la date se prononce "twenty exty-six" :)

Comment: Pourquoi bête ? C'est un problème similaire de codage linguistique, une question d'inconnue aussi.

Comment: @LPH Tu n'as pas compris ce que signifie *c'est bête* ici. L'expression ne juge pas la question mais introduit une remarque.

Comment: @jlliagre C'est bien ça, la remarque ne me semble pas bête, c'est une petit détail intéressant.

Comment: *C'est bête* ne signifie pas que la remarque est bête, mais que c'est quelque chose qui est arrivé spontanément à l'esprit de Luke sans qu'il y ait eu de réflexion poussée. On peut aussi dire *c'est marrant* avec sensiblement le même sens sans que ce qui suit ait spécialement besoin d'être drôle.

Comment: @jlliagre Précisémment : je voulais indiquer que je considère que la ressource mentionnée dans mon commentaire n'apporte pas beaucoup à la question malgré l'amusement qu'elle m'offre.

Answer (score 4):

Il n'existe pas de façon habituelle de lire ce type de date vu le peu de fois où on est amené à le rencontrer.

On est donc assez libre de le faire d'une façon ou d'une autre, par exemple :

> Dix huit cent nonante; points de suspension<sup>1</sup>.

ou

> Mille neuf cent quatre vingt dix et quelques; points de suspension.

<sub>1.</sub> <sub>Votre kilométrage peut varier.</sub>

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147159/discussion-on-answer-by-jlliagre-lecture-de-date-incomplete); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Comme dit dans la réponse de @jlliagre il n'existe pas de façon habituelle de lire ce type de date et chaque lecture sera faite en fonction du lecteur et du besoin. Pour une lecture publique, sur une scène par exemple, je n'ajouterais aucun mot mais jouerais sur la diction et la prononciation : « En janvier [milnœfsɑ̃katrəvɛ̃di:] », l'intonation montante sur [vɛ̃di:], le son [i:] prolongé et suivi d'une courte pause traduisant les points de suspension.

Le principe étant de :

- ne pas prononcer l'éventuelle consonne finale de la dizaine.
- faire trainer le son voyelle final de la dizaine.
- prendre une intonation montante sur la dizaine.

[milɥisɑ̃trɑ̃:] 183...
[milnœfsɑ̃vɛ̃:] 192...
[dømildi:] 201...

Comment: Voilà une meilleure idée ; cependant on reste sans ressource pour les autres (193…, 194…, …).

Comment: @LPH Je ne comprends pas « on reste sans ressource pour les autres (193…, 194…, …) » ???

Comment: Comment dit-on dans ces cas-là ; on ne peut certainement pas finir avec un « dix » dont on arrête la prononciation au i.

Comment: @LPH Je ne donnais qu'un exemple à partir de ta question, l'exemple est pour moi entièrement transposable dans toutes les situations. Mais j'ai complété en espérant que ce sera plus clair pour toi. Par ailleurs, je n'ai pas jugé utile de le mentionner mais tout le monde ne subvocalise pas et la question de savoir comment  [lire  dans sa tête] une année tronquée ne se pose pas vraiment (c'est le jardin secret de chacun !)

Comment: Vous ne voulez pas entendre parler des « audio books » ?

Comment: @LPH Quel rapport entre les audio books (lesquels, par essence,  restituent la lecture théâtrale dont je parle dans ma réponse) et la subvocalisation ?

Comment: Il est bien évident que les livres qui sont transcrits en forme audio pour les gens qui aiment à se faire lire la littérature et même d'autres choses, vont devoir comprendre une forme orale de ces dates ; il serait souhaitable d'avoir une et une seule forme que tout le monde comprenne, à moins que l'on rejette l'idée du livre audio, ou qu'on ne la considère pas comme importante.

Comment: Eh bien voici de quoi t'occuper ! Fais donc une « norme ». La liberté d'interprétation est essentielle au travail d'artiste (du moins dans les pays « libres ») et le récipiendaire de l’œuvre artistique aime aussi conserver une latitude dans la façon dont il perçoit l’œuvre.

Comment: Oui, oui! Va travailler sur cette norme, et travailles-y dur et à plein temps.

Comment: @F Si j'avais vocation à travailler sur de telles normes, et SI il existait un consensus qui juge utile telles normes, je trouverais ce travail acceptable, mais je ne vais pas me jeter dans des entreprises de ce genre pour la gloire. // Vous préférez alors rester dans l'indéfinition et ainsi chaque fois que, comme moi, vous avez une question, accéder le FSE, ou autre site, pour vous informer du degré de liberté dont vous jouissez ? Pour ceux qui vont profiter de cette libre expression, idem, qu'ils aillent voir sur le FSE un bon petit moment pour comprendre la variante qui leur est imposée ?

Comment: @LPH  Je n'ai  pas à m'informer de mon « degré de liberté » pour m’approprier la langue. La langue est une matière vivante en constante évolution et à laquelle chaque individu participe, même de façon infinitésimale. J'adore néologiser et j'adore découvrir de nouveaux vocables, farfouiller dans les dictionnaires.  Rester dans l'indéfinition ?  Dans le domaine de la langue je n'ai jamais eu cette impression. J'hésite parfois sur certaines règles grammaticales parce que quand on s'exprime publiquement il faut respecter certaines normes, mais ça ne va pas plus loin et l'incertitude est éphémère.

Comment: @None Non, personne n'est  trop souvent dans l'indéfinition ; je ne parlait que du présent cas ; si quelqu'un a une façon de lire puis qu'une autre personne en a une autre, et encore et encore, celui qui entend ça est vite perdu quant à ce qui se trouve derrière les mots, d'autant plus qu'on ne sait pas nécessairement si la différence est justifiée ou comment la justifier.

Comment: @LPH Si l'acteur est bon, l'auditeur ne sera pas perdu, et s'il l'est un moment il suffit d'un peu de réflexion pour comprendre. L'art n'est pas une science.

Comment: Ou bien on est tous dans "l'indéfinition", dans le sens que de toute façon, chacun vient avec le bagage de son vécu et de ses associations et résonances personnelles avec les mots, et que ce qu'on dit peut très bien être interprété ou ressenti de façon différente par ses interlocuteurs... Impossible d'avoir un langage sans aucune "ambiguïté".

Comment: @None Bien forcé d'être d'accord sur le fait que l'art n'est pas une science.